# Rails 4: Concatenate date and time fields before sending form to soap xml webservice/api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, web-services, datetime, soap

Joining or concatenating two separate date and time fields to one datetime entry in a Rails database appears to be a fairly common problem. In my example I'm trying to concatenate :dining_date with :dining_time to make :dining_date_and_time. But after a lot of googling and trying out a number of similar stackoverflow solutions, I still keep getting an error message back from the soap xml webservice that I'm trying to request.

I've played around in SoapUI and the webservice I'm using and I can see it is very sensitive to having T before the time. This is the exact format it requires:
Example: `2015-06-25T18:00:00`

Perhaps I'm not interpolating the "T" character correctly here, but I've tried lots of combinations and can't get it to work.

Anyway here's full error trace from the webservice (I'm using the Savon gem as my SOAP client in Rails and it's been working fine so far)

```
Savon::SOAPFault at /
(soap:Client) System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 607). ---> System.FormatException: The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.
   at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags kinds)
   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read32_BookReservationRequest(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read193_BookReservation()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer20.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at
```

Relevant part of my view:

```
<h1>Book Reservation New Form:</h1>

  <%= form_tag(root_url, :method => :get ) %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= label_tag 'Partner Code (identifies how user has reached this point - restaurant + channel):' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :partner_code %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= label_tag 'Restaurant Location ID (which area in restaurant they are seating (dropdown):' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :restaurant_location_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= label_tag 'Select dining session:' %>
  <%= select_tag(:session_id, options_for_select([['Breakfast'], ['Lunch'], ['Dinner']])) %>
  </div> 

 <div class="field">
     <%= label_tag 'Dining Date:' %>      
     <%= text_field_tag(:dining_date) %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
     <%= label_tag 'Dining Date:' %>      
     <%= text_field_tag(:dining_time) %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
   <%= hidden_field_tag :dining_date_and_time %>
 </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= label_tag 'Party size: (dropdown)' %>
  <%= select_tag(:size, options_for_select([['1 person', 1 ], ['2 people', 2], ['3 people', 3], ['4 people', 4], ['5 people', 5], ['6 people', 6], ['7 people', 7], ['8 people', 8], ['9 people', 9], ['10 people', 10], ['11 people', 11], [ '12 people', 12]])) %>
  </div>

<%= render 'personal_details' %> 

<%= render 'response' %>
```

My latest attempt in model (have also tried before_save and before_validation callbacks):

```
class BookReservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :confirmation_number, :reservation_id 

  before_create do
      self.dining_date_and_time = "#{dining_date} #{"T"} #{dining_time}"
    end  

  def client
    client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://example-wsdl-link", follow_redirects: :follow_redirects)
  end   

  def initialize(partner_code, restaurant_location_id, session_id, dining_date_and_time, size, first_name, last_name, email, guest_accepts_email_marketing)
      message = { 'PartnerCode' => partner_code, 'RestaurantLocationId' => restaurant_location_id, 'SessionId' => session_id, 'DiningDateAndTime' => dining_date_and_time, 'Size' => size }
      message.merge!('Booker' => {'UserWithoutALogin' => { 'FirstName' => first_name, 'LastName' => last_name, 'EMail' => email, 'GuestAcceptsEmailMarketingFromPartner' => guest_accepts_email_marketing }})

      response = client.call(:book_reservation, message: message)
      if response.success?
      data = response.to_array(:book_reservation_response).first
      if data
        @confirmation_number = data[:confirmation_number]
        @reservation_id = data[:reservation_id]
      end
      end
  end  

end
```

Controller:

```
class BookReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def index    
    if params[:partner_code] && params[:restaurant_location_id] && params[:session_id] && params[:dining_date_and_time] && params[:size] && params[:first_name] && params[:last_name] && params[:email] && params[:guest_accepts_email_marketing]
      @book_reservation = BookReservation.new params[:partner_code], params[:restaurant_location_id], params[:session_id], params[:dining_date_and_time], params[:size], params[:first_name], params[:last_name], params[:email], params[:guest_accepts_email_marketing]
    end
  end 

  def book_reservation_params
    params.require(:book_reservation).permit(:partner_code, :restaurant_location_id, :session_id, :dining_date_and_time, :size, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :guest_accepts_email_marketing, :confirmation_number, :reservation_id, :dining_date, :dining_time)  
  end

end
```

Table in schema (dining_date_and_time is rails datetime datatype) (don't need this just for basic soap request but will need a database to store these inputs eventually and BookReservation model won't work as Activerecord without it):

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150625100835) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "book_reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "partner_code"
    t.integer  "restaurant_location_id"
    t.string   "session_id"
    t.datetime "dining_date_and_time"
    t.string   "size"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.boolean  "guest_accepts_email_marketing"
  end

end
```

Thanks very much in advance! Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've also tried this in model: `class BookReservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :confirmation_number, :reservation_id
  before_save :concatenate

  def concatenate
      dining_date_and_time = "#{dining_date} T #{dining_time}"
    end` but no value is shown in params (looking in terminal) ie: "dining_date"=>"2015-06-25", "dining_time"=>"17:00:00", "dining_date_and_time"=>"" I'm doing something fundamentally wrong but can't work it out!

Comment: You may need `self.dining_date` and `self.dining_time` depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your interpolation is incorrect.  Whatever appears within the quotes will appear in the output, so when you have `"#{dining_date} #{"T"} #{dining_time}"`, Rails will insert a blank before and after your "T".

Separately, I don't see any formatting or validation at all for your date and time fields.  The chances that a user will enter '2015-06-25' for the date and '18:00:00' for the time are rather small.  You may want to implement a datepicker for your date - the user gets a nice pop up calendar to select from and you can use that to enforce your desired format.  For the time field, if you don't use some sort of time picker control, you will want to add some validation to make sure the user enters a proper time.  This can be done in your model and, optionally, on the client side as well to prevent the user from submitting the form with an invalid time.

Once you have valid input, you can use `strftime` to format as needed.  From my console:

```
>> foo = "2015-06-25"   #from datepicker in your view
=> "2015-06-25"
>> bar = "2 pm"         #validated time
=> "2 pm"
>> (foo + ' ' + bar).to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")     #combine date and time and format as needed
=> "2015-06-25T14:00:00"
```

Comment: Hi Steve thanks for your reply. I already have a date and time picker for client-side validation. I'm trying this in model now, but still getting empty string in params:  `before_create do
    self.dining_date_and_time = (self.dining_date + ' ' + self.dining_time).to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%S")        
  end` Any ideas?

Comment: You need to either populate the instance from `params` or call this from inside your create action after you populate the instance (but before you try to save).  The latter would be my preference but either should work.  In a `before_create` action, `self` is not yet populated with the `params` from your form.

Comment: So would I just use before_save in BookReservation model or do you mean the logic must be within the actual method involved with making the soap request? I tried Glupo's way in the controller but the syntax is quite messy and hard to understand.

Comment: Whatever method your form posts to should have some line of code like `@reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)`.  That is taking your permitted parameters from the view (`params`) and loading them into a new reservation instance.  Once you do that, you can access `@reservation.dining_date` and such.  Alternatively, you should be able to keep your code as is and just use `params[:dining_date]` in that `before_create` method, but it is not so great to access `params` directly from multiple places.

Comment: Sorry Steve, I'm still really stumped, as i understand it, this is the final (but not ideal) code I should have: `class BookReservation
  attr_reader :confirmation_number, :reservation_id
  before_save :convert
  def convert
    params[:dining_date_and_time] = params[dining_date] + ' ' + params[dining_time].to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%S")
  end` but now I'm getting: undefined method `before_save' for BookReservation:Class - am I close?

Comment: @dan I bet you are close but can you put all code updates in your OP?  It is very hard to read code in a comment.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to add this to my model < ActiveRecord::Base - in any case, even with above code dining_date_and_time field remains empty on submit

Comment: Any access to attributes of the params hash should look like `params[:dining_date]` - don't forget the colon.

Comment: Damn, forgot colons, but still not working - here's the full model code in gist: https://gist.github.com/daneasterman/f5635077d9aa8231d52e

Comment: So your BookReservation instances are getting created successfully and everything from your form is there except for `dining_date_and_time`?  For one, you missed wrapping the date/time calc in parens but there is something else going on.

Comment: You might be on the right track but I would expect to see a controller action that your form posts to - do you have that?  IMO that would be a better place from which to call something like the convert method.  Also, another issue is that I don't think params from your view are available in your model methods unless you pass from your controller.

Comment: My controller is extremely messy and bad practice but if I try to refactor it, it breaks everything ie. if I try to enclose it in (reservation_params). I only have an index action in controller at the moment as shown above. How do I pass params from controller to model? should I definitely stick to doing some form of before callback in controller?

Comment: Is everything working except for calculating `dining_date_and_time`?  Objects getting created and saved?

Comment: Yes the object is getting created but I'm not actually saving it in the controller yet, I just realised this is the silly thing I'm doing wrong. Will start working on it again tomorrow with fresh mind

Comment: Meanwhile any idea when I put: book_reservation.new(book_reservation_params) - abbreviated - it throws wrong arguments errors?

Comment: Yes, book_reservation does not exist.  To get a new instance it would be BookReservation.new...

Comment: Have you used the rails console at all?  I find that very helpful to try things as I am learning Ruby and Rails.  Easier than editing my code, running, debugging etc.

Comment: Not so far on this project but how would I do that to test out a before_save callback? I suppose I could only test out the instance is being created and saved correctly

Comment: Yes hard to test flow but you can definitely check syntax and even small code fragments.  Well GL...

Answer (score 0):

Well,

To begin with,

This block:

```
before_create do
  self.dining_date_and_time = "#{dining_date} #{"T"} #{dining_time}"
end
```

is not reached, `before_create` fires when you save new object. Otherwise it would have thrown `undefined local variable or method 'dining_date'` since your model has no chance to get this field.

Instead of checking in `index` method of controller for persistence of required params, this should be validated in model like that

```
    class BookReservation < ActiveRecord::Base
      validate :your, :required, :fields, presence: :true
    ...
    end
```

And in your controller should only be call to the model.

Turning back to your original question [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3311657/steve-klein) has given the best decision. `(foo + ' ' + bar).to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")`

I've taken a risk to refactor your code a little and organize it a bit more "rails-way"

http://pastebin.com/CDhReHcA

Comment: Thanks for your help and refactoring advice, Glupo but rails is telling me it doesn't like the + in the controller: "NoMethodError at /
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass" - I've tried interpolation over concatenation but can't get the syntax right? What should I do?

Comment: My bad, it should be `params[:book_reservation][:dining_date_and_time] = "#{(params[:book_reservation][:dining_date] + ' ' + params[:book_reservation][:dining_time]).to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")}"` Also you should handle situations when no date given. This code needs refinement for your need and that's for you to do.

Comment: I'm now getting undefined method '[]' with this, my guess is that this logic should be in the model and would be a lot clearer there. But not sure how to implement that.

Comment: Since what we need is to modify params before we pass them to create new model instance it should be handled in controller. I looked again at your controller and understood i got tricked by your `book_reservation_params` method. As far as I understand you are getting plain params and will need to remove `require` from `book_reservation_params`